# Find out the PID of an application

Tags: terminal, applescript

I am developing apps with Unity 3D, and often have several instances of the program open. When I go to debug my scripts, Monodevelop (the script editing and debugger tool) shows me a list of all open Unity applications and their Process Identifiers (PIDs), so that I can choose which one to attach to.

[image: Pick a Unity, any Unity!]

Unfortunately, I often have no idea which PID belongs to the instance of Unity that is running the scripts I wish to debug.

Is there a way to:

- put the PID in the title bar of the application?
- see the PID and text on the window's title bar, in some helper application?
- select an application by PID an bring it to the foreground?

I have tried:

- looking at the applications in System Preferences -- they all show up as Unity (and quitting them one by one is hardly ideal)
- running `ps auxww | grep Unity` -- they were launched with the same path and command so I can't tell them apart
- dabbling with AppleScript -- I suspect the answer might lie here, but I find it a very confusing language

Comment: This is probably better placed in stack overflow

Comment: Would it help to have the PID of the process whose UI is active at that moment? I. e., `tell app "System Events" to get (process 1 whose frontmost is true)'s unix id`

Comment: @Synoli, it absolutely would. (I see that script has potential, but I don't know how to run it without Script Editor being in the foreground).

Comment: @Kevin, I suppose I could try there, but this isn't actually a programming question and thus I thought it fit in better here.

I was really hoping there might be a handy little application that'd show the PID of each window in the title bar of the window, but, maybe the problem is too obscure to have a solution like that.

Comment: Does this help you out? https://superuser.com/questions/902869/how-to-identify-which-process-is-running-which-window-in-mac-os-x

Comment: @Kevin, that looks very helpful.